# Does UserDetailsService username must be the same as UserDetails username by contract?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

```
public interface UserDetailsService {
/**
 * Locates the user based on the username. In the actual implementation, the search
 * may possibly be case sensitive, or case insensitive depending on how the
 * implementation instance is configured. In this case, the <code>UserDetails</code>
 * object that comes back may have a username that is of a different case than what
 * was actually requested..
 * @param username the username identifying the user whose data is required.
 * @return a fully populated user record (never <code>null</code>)
 * @throws UsernameNotFoundException if the user could not be found or the user has no
 * GrantedAuthority
 */
UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException;}
```

loadUserByUsername param is username

```
public interface UserDetails extends Serializable {
/**
 * Returns the username used to authenticate the user. Cannot return
 * <code>null</code>.
 * @return the username (never <code>null</code>)
 */
String getUsername()}
```

getUsername return username

**Does this username must be the same value in both by interface contract?**
For example i want `loadUserByUsername(String username)` username be an email and `String getUsername()` be an UserID. Load by email, but return UserDetails with username as UserID.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, if you load user by username you will search it form DB by username.

Comment: yea, but i want then return UserDetails instance where String getUsername(){return id;}

Comment: the UserDetails interface is provided by springSecurity API and you c'annot implement it.

Answer (score -1):

this is the way I implement it:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.1/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-jdbc

AppUserServices class

```
@Service
public class AppUserServices implements AppUserService{


@Autowired
    private AppUserRepository repo;
    
    @Override
    public AppUser fetchByUsername(String username) {
        return repo.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public void persist(AppUser appUser) {
        repo.save(appUser);     
    }

 }
```

AppUserDetailServices class

```
@Service
public class AppUserDetailServices implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
private AppUserService service;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    Optional<AppUser> user = Optional.ofNullable(service.fetchByUsername(username));
    
    if(user.isPresent()) {
        User  dbuser = new User(
                user.get().getUsername(),
                user.get().getPassword(),
                user.get().getAuthorities());
        return dbuser;
    } else {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't answer my question:)

Comment: You can use username be an email, phone number etc.

Comment: But i want to login with for ex. email and then return User with UserID username instead of email.